# How to make other microservices aware of the IP address of the consul for service registry

Tags: docker, dockerfile, microservices, consul

I am currently dockerizing a micro-service application and using Consul for service discovery. So all the services register themselves with the consul and also get their environmental variables from the consul. The starting script of the undockerized micro service application takes the Consul ip:port from the user and forwards it to all the other microservices which is good. But how do I replicate the same for dockerized microservice application as each container is independent. Also, all the services need to register themselves with the consul but they don't have the consul ip.

I can hardcode the consul ip:port in each of the required microservice application but I don' t think that's an elegant way. So do you have any idea on how to make other services aware of the consul ip?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the  consul IP & Port as environment variable(s) to your dockers (`-e` on the `docker run` command)

Comment: Great!  Can we also pass this as an environmental variable using docker compose?

Comment: @ArnonRotem-Gal-Oz Can you share example of environmental variable using docker compose

Comment: @flik see the docker compose documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: actually, I am confusing with Port as environment example :     environment:
      - ADDRESS=consul1

Answer (score 0):

Consul provides a [DNS interface](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html). Don't use ip addresses, if you do you're not *really* doing any kind of service discovery.

The best thing to do is set up [DNS Forwarding](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/forwarding.html) in your DNS infrastructure, and then do a lookup for consul.service.consul.